# gulp: build the code and start it in the browser

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, gulp-task

So I want to use `elm` language for a web project and I need the project to be in `visual studio 2015` and I am using gulp. My issue is that I don't know how to create a `gulp task` that builds the code and starts it in the browser. Here is what I've done so far:

gulpfile.js:

```
/// <binding ProjectOpened='default' />
var gulp = require('gulp')
var elm = require('gulp-elm')
var gutil = require('gulp-util')
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber')
var connect = require('gulp-connect')

// File paths
var paths = {
    dest: 'build',
    elm: 'src/*.elm',
    static: 'src/*.{html,css}'
}

// Init Elm
gulp.task('elm-init', elm.init)

// Compile Elm to HTML
gulp.task('elm', ['elm-init'], function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.elm)
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(elm())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest))
})

// Move static assets to dist
gulp.task('static', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.static)
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest))
})

// Watch for changes and compile
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.elm, ['elm'])
    gulp.watch(paths.static, ['static'])
})

// Local server
gulp.task('connect', function () {
    connect.server({
        root: 'dist',
        port: 3000
    })
})

// Main gulp tasks
gulp.task('build', ['elm', 'static'])
gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'build', 'watch'])
```

The `connect` task does not opens the site in the browser. So, how to achieve this? I want to start the site by clicking on a task (from the task explorer windows in visual studio) and click start and it should compile the code and start.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gulp-connect` package doesn't automatically open a browser window for you. It may have done so in older versions.

However, there is a fork in the [`gulp-connect-multi`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-multi) that includes the ability to open a browser on connect.

Otherwise, you can use the [`gulp-open`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-open) package directly to open a browser window.